# Slice numpy array based on x number of other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I am trying to make my current code dynamic. Meaning it should be able to adjust regardless of the number of array inputs of the user.

Current code:

```
main1 = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
array1 = numpy.array(['a','b','c','b'])
my_list1 = ['a','b']
array2 = numpy.array(['cat','dog','bird','cat'])
my_list2 = ['cat']

result_array = main1[np.in1d(array1, my_list1) and np.in1d(array2, my_list2)]
```

The desired result of printing out `result_array` is:

```
array([1, 4])
```

This is because of the intersection of `a` and `cat & b` and `cat`.

My goal is to be able to do this with an n number of `array1`, `array2` ... and n number of `my_list1`, `my_list2`...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version for more than two arrays, using `logical_and.reduce`:

```
array3 = numpy.array(['cat3','dog3','bird3','cat3'])
my_list3 = ['cat3']

my_arrays = [array1, array2, array3]
my_lists = [my_list1, my_list2, my_list3]
res1 = main1[numpy.logical_and.reduce(tuple(np.in1d(array, lst) for 
                                            array, lst in zip(my_arrays, my_lists)))]
```

Test it:

```
res2 = main1[np.in1d(array1, my_list1) & np.in1d(array2, my_list2) &
             np.in1d(array3, my_list3)]
```

Looks good:

```
>>> np.all(res1 == res2)
True
```

Old answer two arrays only.

This should work:

```
my_arrays = [array1, array2]
my_lists = [my_list1, my_list2]
main1[np.logical_and(*(np.in1d(array, lst) for array, lst in zip(my_arrays, my_lists)))]
```

Result:

```
array([1, 4])
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! I thought it was working with three arrays and three lists but apparently it only considers up to the second pair of array-lists. How can we make the np.logical_and consider more than 2 arguments?